# Issue in getting facebook ad campaign details using curl and python code

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

Please help me in fixing curl command and python code. I am putting the secret key, but unable to get the `CAMPAIGN_ID`. I have created an ad for my facebook page, but couldn't find `CAMPAIGN_ID`, I have tried to use Ad id, but that also didn't work.

```
curl -G \
     -d "level=ad" \
     -d "fields=impressions,ad_id" \
     -d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<CAMPAIGN_ID>/insights"
```

I also used the python code below, but got a few errors.

```
from facebook_business.objects import AdCampaign
    campaign = AdCampaign('<AD_CAMPAIGN_ID>')
    params = {
                    'date_preset': AdCampaign.Preset.last_7_days,
    }
    insights = campaign.get_insights(params=params)
    print insights
```

Below is the error:

> ````py
> traceback (most recent call last):
> File "fbAds2.py", line 1, in <module>
> from facebook_business.objects import AdCampaign
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facebook_business.objects'```
> ````

Comment: It seems like you haven't imported the facebook_business.objects to your code.  I suspect you try to do this inside your main function? Try to place that in the top of your code, not inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error so I changed the code a bit and got results

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi

app_id = 'zzzzzzzz'
app_secret = 'yyyyyyyy'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'

campaign = Campaign('xxxxxxxx')

insights = campaign.get_insights()
print(insights)
```